# NDSolve not able to solve a system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

Here are some basic equations

```
Vn = -Mn/Sqrt[R^2 + z^2 + cn^2];
Vd = -Md/Sqrt[b^2 + R^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2];
Vh = υ0^2/2 Log[R^2 + β*z^2 + ch^2];
Vt = Vn + Vd + Vh;
V = Vt + Lz^2/(2*R^2);
Vt = V /. {R -> R[t], z -> z[t]};
```

the values of the parameters

```
Mn = 250; cn = 0.25;
Md = 7000; b = 6; a = 3; h = 0.2;
υ0 = 20; β = 1.5; ch = 8.5;
Lz = 10;
En = 600;
```

the forces along R and z coordinates

```
FR = -D[V, R];
Fz = -D[V, z];
FRt = FR /. {R -> R[t], z -> z[t]};
Fzt = Fz /. {R -> R[t], z -> z[t]};
```

the system of the differential equations

```
DifferentialEquations[R0_, z0_, pR0_, pz0_] := 
  Module[{Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4},

  Deq1 = R'[t] == pR[t];
  Deq2 = z'[t] == pz[t]; 
  Deq3 = pR'[t] == FRt;
  Deq4 = pz'[t] == Fzt;

{Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4, R[0] == R0, z[0] == z0, pR[0] == pR0, pz[0] == pR0} 

]
```

the initial conditions

```
R0 = 5;
z0 = 0;
pR0 = 0;
pz0 = Sqrt[2*(En - V) - pR0^2] /. {R -> R0, z -> z0}
tmax = 500;
```

and the integration loop

```
sdeq = DifferentialEquations[R0, z0, pR0, pz0];
data0 = {};
sol = NDSolve[sdeq, {R[t], z[t], pR[t], pz[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     MaxSteps -> Infinity,  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> z[t], "Direction" -> -1,           
 "EventAction" :> 
  AppendTo[data0, {{R[t], pR[t]}, {R[t], -pR[t]}}], 
 Method -> "Adams"}];
```

Mathematica does not report any mistakes the integration loop. However no output is produced (empty data0 list) the program consumes all the available memory until it crashes.

Any ideas about what cause this? Also any suggestions for code improvements are more than welcome!

Comment: I copied and ran your code, which took only several seconds.  `R[t]` and `pR[t]` are rapidly oscillating functions, while `z[t]` and `pz[t]` appear to be zero.  Note that Fzt is proportional to z, so if z starts at zero it would appear to stay at zero.

Comment: D0 you mean that `data0` is not empty? If not, can you please make a quick `ListPlot` of the elements of the list?

Comment: No, `data0` is empty, as it would be for `z[t]` identically zero.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z: Your code is ok except for one typo, a semicolon before tmax. The commands should read: R0 = 5; z0 = 0; pR0 = 0; pz0 = Sqrt[2*(En - V) - pR0^2] /. {R -> R0, z -> z0} ; tmax = 500;

Answer (score 6):

The code as displayed in the Question runs fine for me using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 under Windows 8.1 (64 bit).  However, as I noted in a Comment, `z0 = 0` causes `z[t]` to remain zero.  Arbitrarily, I set `z0 = 0.1` (and also `tmax = 5`), which produced

[image: z[t]]

with `data0`

```
 {{{3.02779, -18.7347}, {3.02779, 18.7347}}, {{4.02275, 13.1626}, {4.02275, -13.1626}}, 
 {{1.7836, -24.1793}, {1.7836, 24.1793}}, {{4.16014, 12.1853}, {4.16014, -12.1853}},
 {{1.52373, -25.3168}, {1.52373, 25.3168}}, {{4.2339, 11.586}, {4.2339, -11.586}},
 {1.21978, -26.7392}, {1.21978, 26.7392}}, {{4.35913, 10.4842}, {4.35913, -10.4842}}, 
 {{0.67748, -29.6552}, {0.67748, 29.6552}}, {{4.57951, 8.54321}, {4.57951, -8.54321}},
 {{0.582273, -30.0941}, {0.582273, 30.0941}}, {{4.68988, 7.3793}, {4.68988, -7.3793}}, 
 {{0.499859, -30.1679}, {0.499859, 30.1679}}, {{4.85037, 5.13218}, {4.85037, -5.13218}}, 
 {{0.236406, -9.23721}, {0.236406, 9.23721}}}
```